# strange result for str_to_date in mysql

Tags: mysql

A developer created a table for us, and made a date field as VARCHAR(255) and a field name of "Requested Ship Date".

First yes I know these both are bad database management, but I  was not involved at the creation point, just now in the please run reports against it point.

So, I am trying to convert this field to a date value, and was using `STR_TO_DATE(Requested Ship Date,"%m/%d/%y")` (it has the correct syntax in the code)

The problem is I am getting a weird result.  'Requested Ship Date' = 5/31/2017 after the conversion it comes out as 2020-05-31.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just store dates as dates and stop with all this silliness

Answer (score 1):

`%y` is the year without the century, `%Y` is the year *with* the century.

So 2017 is being interpreted as '20, which is 2020.

Comment: by shouldn't it be putting the date in the format of 5/31/20 and not 2020-05-31?

Comment: If I'm reading your code correctly you're asking to convert *from* a date of format `MM/DD/YY`, not to.

Answer (score 0):

This is the results I am getting from my query

05/30/2017  05/31/2017  2017-05-30

05/30/2017  05/31/2017  2017-05-30

05/31/2017  05/31/2017  2017-05-31

Here is the actual code for the Query

```
    select  `Requested Ship Date`,
            `Actual Post Goods Issue date`,
            STR_TO_DATE(`Requested Ship Date`,'%m/%d/%Y')
    FROM        `previous day shipments`
    WHERE       LENGTH(`Serial Number`) = 0
```